# How to specifiy the location for a unit test in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

When using VS 2010, I like to organize the projects in my solutions by creating them in subfolders in the OS. For example I would place a project called MySolution.Core.Shared in G:\Projects\MySolution\Core\Shared.  I will also create a Solution folder in Solution Explorer to hold the project as well.  This works well for other templates, but the automated unit test creation process does not.  VS always creates the unit test project in the solution's root folder, so I have to then unload the test project, move the project (after closing VS or I get a file open error for some reason) and then reopen the solution and remount the project in the appropriate point in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was never able to find a true answer to this, but I did find an acceptable solution.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Create the test project manually by first right clicking on the
   solution folder where you wish to place your new tests and choosing
   the Add -> New Project option.
2. Select the Tests->Test Project Template.
3. Give it an appropriate name and choose the appropriate Location in
   the provided slots.
4. Go to the object/member you wish to test and select Create Unit
   Tests in the right click menu.
5. Choose the test project you just created in the spot provided at the
   bottom of the resultant dialog box.

Voila!  You are done and your unit tests are now nice and snugly placed in your file structure of choice.